# Interpreting fundamental theorem of calculus when the domain of $x$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: integration

I will try to explain my question throughly as possible.

According to the wikipedia, it explains the fundamental theorem of calculus as:

Let f be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval [a, b]. Let F be the function defined, for all x in [a, b], by

$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$.

Then, F is uniformly continuous on [a, b], differentiable on the open interval (a, b), and

$F'(x) = f(x)$ for all x in (a,b).

So for example, if we have the function $f(t) = \frac{1}{t^2-1}$. If the domain of $x$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$. My thought is to use this theorem I have consider when $(-\infty, a]$ and $[a, \infty)$. So for example. If $a$ is 1, then

$F(x) = \int_1^x f(t)dt$.

Hence need to consider

$F(\infty) = \int_1^{\infty} f(t)dt$ and $F(-\infty) = \int_1^{-\infty} f(t)dt$. Since the second one is invalid, then $F(-\infty) = -\int_{-\infty}^{1} f(t)dt$.

Using this, can we say $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all x in $(-\infty, 1)$ and $(1, \infty)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain of $x$? Surely $x$ isn't a function. The domain of $f$ (which is a function) cannot be $(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: Assuming your integrals actually converge... What would happen if you replace the number $1$ by some other (finite) number?

Comment: Also: You can just define $F\left(x\right)$ for finite $x$ and then consider the limit, no need to define values at infinity that will likely run into certain problems...

Comment: If $f(t) = \frac{1}{t^2-1}$ then $f$ has a pole at $1$, so $F(x) = \int_1^x f(t)\;dt$ does not exist for any $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an integral is only defined on $[a, b]$ as $a<b<\infty$.
for any function f, $f(\infty)$ is not even to be defined. what you can ask instead is on $$lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 
 f(x)$$
does it exist? infinite? 
when looking on Improper integral defined on $(a, \infty)$ as $a <\infty$, this integral can only be discussed on if $$lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
 \intop_{a}^{x}
 f < \infty$$ but even before that, more significantly - does this limit even exist. 
further more, for on the two diffrent intrvals, $(a,\infty), (-\infty, a)$ you can say $F'(x) = f(x)$ if and only if  $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
 \intop_{a}^{x}
 f < \infty$ and  $lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}
 \intop_{x}^{a}
 f < \infty$ both are finite and same sign (**both** must be non-negetive $(\leq)$ **or** negative).
in ant other terms, the answer is **defiantly no**.